# Can anyone explain this expression piece by piece please? grep '\([aeiou]\).\1'

Tags: grep

I found this expression for a homework assignment that will "print all lines containing a vowel (a, e, i, o, or u) followed by a single character followed by the same vowel again. Thus, it will find “eve” or “adam” but not “vera”." The expression works correctly but I am looking for someone who can explain what each part does so I can further understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, google for regex sites. They will help you a lot. For example, try regexone.

Secondly, to test or help with understanding regexes, refer to regex101.com - this can help you a lot, since it explains what happens step by step; you can also test regexes.

Now as for expression:

```
[aeiou]
```

matches any of characters in brackets(here: a, e, i, o or u).

```
.
```

matches any single character

```
\1
```

matches the first capture group.

```
\(anything\)
```

is a capture group.

Capture group is name for a string that you can remember for later use. In this case, capturing any character from [aeiou] allows us to remember what we matched. If we wrote this regex instead:

```
[aeiou].[aeiou]
```

we would have no way to check whether the first and second vowel were the same.

So, your regex means "Match anything that is one of characters from "aeiou", then any single character, and than whatever was the first character".

Answer (score 1):

First, the `\(` and `\)`. This means "anything inside these escaped parens is a group and can be referenced as such later in the expression". Inside that you have `[aeiou]`, which means "any of the characters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`". The single dot, `.`, means "any single character". The `\1` means "The thing you found when you matched on the first group".